# Visual Studio Code Debugging with dotnet cli watch option

Tags: debugging, npm, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, dotnet-cli

I am able to debug aspnet.core webapi with { request: launch, type: coreclr, program: **.dll } or to update webapi code without restarting server with npm task { start: "dotnet watch run" }.
But I am not able to use both features in the same session. I tried to attach to both browser or server with no luck.

I'd also like to know if this is possible with current version of vscode.

Comment: What SDK version are you using? I.e. what is the output of `dotnet --version`?

Answer (score 3):

[According to this GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/DotNetTools/issues/151), is is not possible to use VS Code with the the `dotnet watch` option.

> Q: How to configure vs code debugger to use dotnet watch?
>
> A: I don't think this is feasible...